# Cannot pass by reference in D language

Tags: reference, pass-by-reference, d

I have a constructor inside the class testclass

```d
@safe public nothrow this(ref Socket socket) {
    // Inside class modulename.classname
    this.socket = socket;
}
```

When I initialize an object of this type in my main method however, I got a few compile errors.

```d
void main() {
    auto variablename = new modulename.classname(
        cast(Socket) new TcpSocket() // main.d line 5
    );
}
```

Errors:

```
main.d(5): Error: constructor testmodule.testclass.this (ref 
Socket socket) is not callable using argument types (Socket)
main.d(5): Error: no constructor for testclass
```

Why cannot I pass the socket by reference?

Comment: passing `socket` by ref is pointless in this case because you never assign to it. the type `Socket` is already a ref (a pointer under the covers) so passing it by ref ends up being a reference to a reference (e.g. a pointer to a pointer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you shouldn't need to pass classes by ref

classes are kept by reference by default (to avoid the slicing problem when inheriting) so you are only passing a pointer in both cases anyway

the problem in your code is that `cast(Socket) new TcpSocket()` is a rvalue which can't be assigned to and thus cannot be passed by ref

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is incorrect in stating:

> you shouldn't need to pass classes by ref
> classes are kept by reference by default

Classes are reference types, but the reference to a class is passed *by value* as the method argument. This only comes into play when you are modifying what the reference refers to.

For example, the usual case when modifying class members is applied either way:

```D
import std.stdio;

class K {
    int i;   
}

void main()
{
    auto k = new K();
    k.i = 3;
    NonRef(k);
    writeln(k.i);    // Writes 5
    
    k.i = 3;
    ByRef(k);
    writeln(k.i);    // Writes 5
}

void NonRef(K k) {
    k.i = 5;
}

void ByRef(ref K k) {
    k.i = 5;
}
```

However, consider this:

```D
import std.stdio;

class K {
    int i;   
}

void main()
{
    auto k = new K();
    k.i = 3;
    NonRef(k);
    writeln(k.i);    // Writes 3 !
    
    k.i = 3;
    ByRef(k);
    writeln(k.i);    // Writes 0 !
}

void NonRef(K k) {
    k = new K();
}

void ByRef(ref K k) {
    k = new K();
}
```

As for your question, at the time of this answer D still doesn't support RValues passed by ref. I *presume* this has to do with compiler not knowing what to apply the ref values back to. This is easily overcome by creating a temporary variable, as you did in your answer.

Comment: Well, when you think about the accepted answer, you'll realise that it says "You SHOULDN'T ..." which you misunderstood for "You must not...". How often did you need to pass a reference by reference? Me - never.

Comment: Dejane, the answer was not precise enough in terminology so I wanted to correct it. Shouldn't need means "shouldn't need". In case where we want that effect back, we actually "do need". This same question comes up time and time in C# because that's how it works there too. So I think it is important to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by initializing the Socket outside the constructor call. I'm not sure if this is a bug, or the language is like this intentionally.

```d
void main() {
    auto socket = cast(Socket) new TcpSocket();
    auto variablename = new modulename.classname(
        socket
    );
}
```

Comment: The D language doesn't allow D rvalue references at the moment - or at least I think it doesn't. There's been some discussion, but I don't think anything is in the current trunk yet.